# Microsoft Graph Powershell - Azure AD SAML Application Attributes and Claims not updated in Portal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to automate the bulk configuration of SAML enterprise applications in AzureAD via the Microsoft Graph API in PowerShell

I'm able to create the app and assign users/groups to it using PowerShell.

But the changes made to Attributes and Claims using PowerShell aren't reflected in the portal.
I created a claims mapping policy using the command **(New-MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy)** and try assigning it to an app (ServicePrincipal) using the command **New-MgServicePrincipalClaimMappingPolicyByRef**, it is updated when I use **Get-MgServicePrincipalClaimMappingPolicy**.

But in the portal it shows the old default values and it doesn't allow to update it in portal. It says **"The configuration was overwritten by a claim mapping policy created via Graph/PowerShell"**

The claims updated via powershell aren't reflected here in portal, it shows the default values in portal.
[image: attributes not updated in portal]

Also, it disabled the updating of attributes in the portal.
[image: disabled in portal]

After bulk creation of apps and updation of the attributes/claims for multiple apps using PowerShell automation, I want it to reflect in the portal for administrators to view/update the attributes in the future.

Specifically, I wanted to programmatically update the Attributes/Claims for multiple (hundreds of) SAML apps and changes to reflect in the Azure portal.

Is there a solution to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, it was a hard limitation 

Answer (score 0):

To Configure and automate SAML-based single sign-on for your application using the Microsoft Graph API:

[image]

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api?tabs=http%2Cpowershell-script

Comment: Thanks Mehtab for the answer, I followed this post to do my configuration, but once I updated the attributes and claims using powershell, they don't reflect in the azure portal, also the Attributes and Claims section becomes read-only in Azure portal.